# not able to load data with ViewModel

Tags: swift, mvvm, tableview, viewmodel

- the tableView dataSource is properly set up in the IB
- the viewController identity is properly set as well in the IB

this is my **viewModel**

```
class StatusCodeViewModel {

    let apiClient = APIClient.shared
    var statusCodes: [StatusCode] = []
    let identifier = "statusCodeCell"

    init() {}


    func loadStatusCodes() {
        apiClient.execute(service: .statusCode) { statusCodes in
            self.statusCodes = statusCodes
        }
    }

}
```

and the **viewController** in which I want to load data

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var viewModel: StatusCodeViewModel? {
        didSet {
            if viewModel!.statusCodes.count > 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel = StatusCodeViewModel()
        viewModel!.loadStatusCodes()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let statusCodes = viewModel!.statusCodes as? [StatusCode] {
            return statusCodes.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: viewModel!.identifier)
        cell?.textLabel!.text = viewModel!.statusCodes[indexPath.row].title
        return cell!
    }


}
```

**the data count is 0 and no data is shown in the tableView**

Comment: You never reload the table once the data is loaded from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You have did set on view model which will occur on initialisation.

You will have to implement some kind of callback when the api returns the call - easiest way would be protocol.

```
protocol StatusCodeViewModelDelegate {
    func callFinished()
}

class StatusCodeViewModel {

    let apiClient = APIClient.shared
    var statusCodes: [StatusCode] = []
    let identifier = "statusCodeCell"
    var delegate : StatusCodeViewModelDelegate?

    init() {}


    func loadStatusCodes() {
        apiClient.execute(service: .statusCode) { statusCodes in
            self.statusCodes = statusCodes
            delegate?.callFinished()
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel = StatusCodeViewModel()
    viewModel.delegate = self
    viewModel!.loadStatusCodes()
}

func callFinished() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Don't forget to extend for delegate you just made:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, StatusCodeViewModelDelegate {
```

Or, as @rmaddy suggested, in View model change `loadStatusCodes` to:

```
func loadStatusCodes(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    apiClient.execute(service: .statusCode) { statusCodes in
        self.statusCodes = statusCodes
    }
}
```

Then, in the viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel = StatusCodeViewModel()
    viewModel!.loadStatusCodes {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: A completion close on the `loadStatusCodes` function would also be a typically solution.

Comment: Agree, it will be even less code, but I prefer it this way as you can extract it to extension as well. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

**//This would do !**

```
     func loadStatusCodes(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
               apiClient.execute(service: .statusCode) { statusCodes in
                   self.statusCodes = statusCodes
                   completion()
               }
           }
```

**//    And in ViewController:**

```
               override func viewDidLoad() {
                       super.viewDidLoad()
                       viewModel = StatusCodeViewModel()
                       viewModel?.loadStatusCodes() {
                           self.tableView.reloadData()
                       }
                   }
```